# Updating Dojo provide

Tags: dojo, amd

I am using Dojo 1.9 for a project, but I don't understand the correct alternative of `dojo.provide` in the AMD style as compared to the legacy style. I was reading [this](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/provide.html#id4) documentation page.

So apparanently this is how the old syntax maps to the new one:

**OLD**

```
dojo.provide("acme.Dialog");
dojo.require("dijit._Widget");
dojo.require("dojo.date");
CODE HERE
```

**NEW**

```
define(["dijit/_Widget", "dojo/date"], function(_Widget, date){   ....
     CODE HERE
     return MyWidget;
});
```

I am not sure what exactly am I returning as MyWidget. My code looks something like this:

```
define(["dojo/foo/x","dojo/foo/y"], function(x, y){
    dojo.provide("my.module");     
});
```

What am I supposed to return here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no equivalent to `dojo.provide` in AMD. This call was only ever necessary to inform parts of the system that you intend to create an object at a given place in the global scope from within the file. Now we use AMD module IDs, which are based on filenames, to do that.

From within the AMD module’s factory function, you may return anything, or you may return nothing. If you return something, it becomes the value of the module. So, in legacy:

A module that defines nothing:

```js
dojo.provide("app.nothing");
// some code
```

would become:

```js
// in app/nothing.js
define([], function () {
    // some code
});
```

A module that defines an object:

```js
dojo.provide("app.myModule");
app.myModule = { foo: "foo" };
```

would become:

```js
// in app/myModule.js
define([], function () {
    return { foo: "foo" };
});
```

And a module that defines a constructor using `declare`:

```js
dojo.provide("app.MyClass");
dojo.require("dijit._WidgetBase");
dojo.declare("app.MyClass", dijit._WidgetBase, {});
```

would become:

```js
// in app/MyClass.js
define([ "dojo/_base/declare", "dijit/_WidgetBase" ], function (declare, _WidgetBase) {
    return declare(_WidgetBase, {});
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I just figured this out while looking at the [Dojo Upgrade Hints](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/releasenotes/migration-17.html). Also @paulsm4 answer was very helpful. The confusion was because of the [Dojo Provide documentation in 1.7](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/provide.html)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a greally great tutorial, "Modern Dojo":

http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.7/modern_dojo/

Good quote:

> If you find yourself typing dojo.* or dijit.* or dojox.*, something
>   isn't right.

Basic rationale for the changes to AMD:

> One of the core concepts of "modern" Dojo is that things in the global
>   namespace are bad. There are numerous reasons for this, but in a
>   complex web application, the global namespace can easily become
>   polluted with all manner of code, especially when a lot of
>   organisations use multiple JavaScript frameworks. I won't even mention
>   the nefarious things that can happen from a security standpoint with
>   people intentionally modifying the global namespace. This means in
>   "modern" Dojo, if you are about to access something in the global
>   namespace STOP because you are doing something wrong.
>
> ...
>
> Another core concept is that synchronous operations are slow and
>   asynchronous ones are usually faster. "Legacy" Dojo already had a
>   fairly strong pedigree in asynchronous JavaScript code with the
>   concept of dojo.Deferred, but in "modern" Dojo, it is best to think of
>   everything operating asynchronously.
>
> ...
>
> To strengthen the modularity of Dojo and leverage the concepts above,
>   in 1.7 Dojo adopted the CommonJS module definition called Asynchronous
>   Module Definition (AMD). This meant a fundamental re-write of the Dojo
>   module loader which is usually exposed through the require() and
>   define() functions. You can find full documentation of the loader in
>   the reference guide.. This has fundementally changed the way code is
>   structured.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am going through this page, but confused as I had written my code as per the Dojo 1.7 documentation (http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/provide.html). I am unsure how should I modify my code correctly.

Comment: so if I am not wrong I should do `return declare("my.module",[my.module],{});` inside the define, right?

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure you need to "define()" or "return" anything.  This link might also help: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/quickstart/writingWidgets.html.  It, too, uses the new AMD syntax.

Comment: I see, thanks for the help.! I'll probably read a little more before I proceed. The documentation is a little confusing for me :) (Btw, did you mean `'declare'` or 'return' anything?)