# Dojo provide - update legacy to AMD

Tags: dojo, upgrade, amd, legacy

This is a followup to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19504147/updating-dojo-provide/19508293?noredirect=1#19508293) question.

So I have this pre AMD dojo code :

```
dojo.require(...);
dojo.provide("abc.def.foo");
som.var.iable = {A:1,B:2};
som.var.iable2 = {C: 3, D:som.var.iable.B}
dojo.declare("blah",[],{
     //code based on the above variables
});
```

For AMD, after reading [this](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/provide.html) and the previous link, I am trying something like this

```
som.var.iable = {A:1,B:2};
som.var.iable2 = {C: 3, D:som.var.iable.B}

define([
    "dojo/_base/declare", 
], function(declare){
   return declare("abc.def.foo", null {               
   });
});

define([
    "dojo/_base/declare", 
], function(declare){
   som.var.iable = {A:1,B:2};
som.var.iable2 = {C: 3, D:som.var.iable.B}
   return declare("blah", null {
        //code based on the above variables
   });
});
```

Obviously this fails, as there is no object structure like `som.var.iable`. I can it, but my question is how did it work in the legacy code? and what would be the correct AMD equivalent?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, here are my assumptions about what you're trying to do:

1. You don't *really* need a global variable called `some` with a property `var`, that's just a way to organize stuff
2. You want three modules, `some/var/iable`, `some/var/iable2`, and `blah`. This means three files and three `define()` calls
3. Neither `som.var.iable` nor `som.var.iable2` are real inheritable classes, they're just plain old objects... so only `blah` needs to use `declare()`

---

Thus you should create a file `som/var/iable.js`, which is a provides a plain object:

```
define([
],
function(){
    return {A:1,B,2}
});
```

And another called `som/var/iable2.js`, which is a module that provides a plain object:

```
define([
    "som/var/iable",
],
function(iable){
    return {C: 3, D:iable.B}
});
```

And then your third module `blah.js` that provides a Class-object:

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "som/var/iable2"
],
function(declare,iable2){
    var parentClasses = [];
    var clazz =  declare(parentClasses, {
        constructor : function(){
            // No need for this.inherited(arguments) in this particular case          
            alert("Welcome to the constructor. Did you know that iable2.D is "+iable2.D+"?");   
        },

    });
    return clazz;
});
```

I haven't tested all this, but to kick it off in a page you'd finally want to put:

```
require(["blah",dojo/domReady!"], function(blah){
    var b = new blah();
});
```

Dojo should take care of loading everything in-order so that you get an alert that says

> Welcome to the constructor. Did you know that iable2.D is 2?

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. Yes the variables are w.r.t the organized modules. So in the legacy code, this was taken care of automatically?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure how the legacy code worked, but it looks to me as if it wasn't so much automatic as by-convention. If you used `dojo.provide("foo.bar")`, that just told the system to expect that the global variable `foo` would exist with a property called `bar`, and then you had to ensure it was created on your own.